# Запрет вывода контента если произвольное поле пустое

Tags: php

Всем привет! Есть код, который выводит номер телефона из произвольного поля:

```
<div class="block"><span>Телефон для связи:</span>
<?php echo get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'phone_srevice', true ); ?>
</div>
```

Получается: `Телефон для связи: 000-000-00-00-00`
Но если поле не заполнено, то остается просто `Телефон для связи:`

Как правильно собрать код, что бы, если произвольное поле было пустое, не отображался весь div?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Например добавить проверку

```
<?php if(get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'phone_srevice', true )): ?>
        <div class="block"><span>Телефон для связи:</span>
           <?php echo get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'phone_srevice', true ); ?>
        </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Правда поле лучше сначала сохранить в переменную, чтоб не делать 2 запроса

Comment: А не подскажете как сохранить в переменную?

Comment: @ВалерийЕмельянов Wordpress закеширует данное значение при обращении, это можно подсмотреть в исходном коде функции get_metadata(). В данном случае доп. переменная не нужна.